# Any way to run docker without the Docker Desktop app on windows?

Tags: docker

I really don’t need the Docker Desktop GUI app I really just need the CLI any way to download and run just the cli (so the error docker pipe not found).

EDIT: I don’t want to use or have Docker Desktop GUI part installed I only need the CLI because I never use the GUI part of docker. I installed docker CLI through Choco on windows but when I run docker run and some container it gives me the error I mentioned above. So my question is how to get around that error without having to install the GUI part of Docker (tried it with GUI and it didn’t give that error)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Docker works just fine, installed in WSL2 on Windows.